# RegEx get words with special character

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find words in a string starting with a _ (underscore).

That was easy enough

I wrote this small test program:

```
class Program
{
    private static Regex WordExpression = new Regex(@"_\w+");
    private static string TranslateWord(Match word) => word?.Value?.Replace("_", "");
    private static string Translate(string word)
    {
        return WordExpression.Replace(word, TranslateWord);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Translate("Do you want to _Exit the _Program"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And that worked out very well. The problems starts when there are no spaces between my words:

```
Console.WriteLine(Translate("_Exit_Program"));
```

My expressions only finds one match `_Exit_Program` but I would very much like two matches. Can this be done with a regular expression or would I need to do a split string in my TranslateWord method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
@"_[^\W_]+"
```

The `[^\W_]` negated character class will match any character other than a non-word character (so, it will match all `\w`s) *except* `_`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=_%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%2B&i=Do%20you%20want%20to%20_Exit%20the%20_New_Program)

A more .NET-ish regex will be an expression with [**character class subtraction**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html):

```
_[\w-[_]]+
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=_%5B%5Cw-%5B_%5D%5D%2B&i=Do%20you%20want%20to%20_Exit%20the%20_New_Program)

Here, with `[\w-[_]]`, we match all `\w`s with the exception of `_`.

Use the first suggestion if you need a more portable solution, and the second one if you only plan to use the regex in a .NET environment.